# predis bug Warning: Array to string conversion in ...\vendor\predis\predis\src\Connection\StreamConnection.php on line 366

Tags: php, redis, predis

I store a array (about 50 mb) in redis with predis/predis php lib

```
redisClient->set(key, json_encode($array))
```

Save is successful, but when I try to get data got a bug

```
Warning: Array to string conversion in ...\vendor\predis\predis\src\Connection\StreamConnection.php on line 366

Warning: Array to string conversion in ...\vendor\predis\predis\src\Connection\StreamConnection.php on line 367
```

Result is NULL

How can I solve this problem?

I looked at the code that causes the error, but I still can't figure out how to fix it.